# Remove Codeigniter label wrapping lang()

Tags: php, codeigniter, lang

How do I remove the auto label wrapping that is for the lang() in Codeigniter.

The manual doesn't say anything about it: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/language_helper.html

Do I have to write a function by myself or is there a simple clean way that Im missing?

Comment: Updated my answer with a simple example of how you can extend the language class for strings when you need to pass a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write the second parameter. Keep it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the lang function (found in: `/system/helpers/language_helper.php`):

```
    function lang($line, $for = '', $attributes = array())
    {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $line = $CI->lang->line($line);

            if ($for !== '')
            {
                    $line = '<label for="'.$for.'"'._stringify_attributes($attributes).'>'.$line.'</label>';
            }

            return $line;
    }
```

As you can see it takes 3 parameters. The first parameter is required, but the second two are optional. If you state a second parameter it will return the language string wrapped in a label.

So stating only the first parameter should make it output just the language string.

---

**UPDATE:**

From reading your comment it sounds like you would be better off using the **[language class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/language.html)** directly. However the language class alone will not be enough, you will need to extend it for your purpose. To do this you can create a new file in your `application/core` folder called `MY_lang.php`.

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {

    // You want to extend the line function
    function line($line = '', $value = '')
    {
            $line = ($line == '' OR ! isset($this->language[$line])) ? FALSE : $this->language[$line];

            // We can assume that if a value is passed it is intended to be inserted into the language string
            if($value) {
                    $line = sprintf($line, $value);
            }

            // Because killer robots like unicorns!
            if ($line === FALSE)
            {
                    log_message('error', 'Could not find the language line "'.$line.'"');
            }

            return $line ;
    }
}
```

Assuming your language file has a string like so:

```
$lang['welcome_text'] = "Welcome %s";
```

You could then use this by loading the language class, and using the following code:

```
$name = "foo";
$this->lang->line('welcome_text', $name);
```

The above is 100% untested, so it may need some tweeking, but it should give you somewhere to start from.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The thing is I need to add th second because Im using the following type "Welcome %s" where %s is dynamic value for the name. And code like `lang('welcome_text', $name);` My best option is to go with a custom made function?